# Equidistant Objects with CSS

Tags: html, css

I've read awesome [article](https://css-tricks.com/equidistant-objects-with-css/) and was astonished by the Flexbox Justification method. It works really well, but only when elements fit in the container entirely. I've created [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zz5wubz2/) to illustrate this.

```
#container {  
    text-align: justify;
    font-size: 0.1px; /* IE 9 & 10 don't like font-size: 0; */
    min-width: 600px; 
}
```

How, using this method, can I place the 6th element right after the 5th element without adding extra markup?

Comment: FYI: That has nothing to do with flexbox.

Comment: yeah, but you have to wrap flex container around every row of 4 element, i wander if it is possible without extra divs

Comment: @CBroe: But it should be, and it’s about to be, I guess `;-)`
@user3461664: Your fiddle comprised 6 elements, but it doesn’t matter with flexbox. Did [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31615359/2083613) gave you any pointers?

Answer (score 1):

The sum of widths must not exceed the parent’s width, or there will be no space left to be distributed among them. Fixed (pixel) widths won’t always work on resize. If your six items are 150px each, and the container is, say, 800px in width, there’s no other way than to break into the next line.

Like the author of your article said: it’s more complicated. To stay that way, you could use [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) to have it dynamic. This is just an example:

```
.flex-item{
    width: calc((100% / 6) - 20px); // 100% width ÷ 6 items - 20px space
}
```

Here’s an updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gy04jqdk/

Anyway, flexbox magic is relished best in its pure form. You can achieve the same using [`justify-content:space-between`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content). To make it all work, you also have to add `display:flex` to the parent container. This will make it a flexbox and its immediate children flex-items. The extent of your changes might be limited to:

```
#container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

For visual illustration of element arrangement, the [article at CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) is well-known. You might be also interested in `space-around`, which is another value of `justify-content`.

Also, here’s a fiddle with a fixed width an evenly distributed space: https://jsfiddle.net/fdrgw3eu/

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have a parent element that contains the three elements you would like to arrange in an equidistant manner:

```
.parent {
    width: 100%;
}

.element1 {
  width: 33.3%;
  float: left;
}

.element2 {
  width: 33.3%;
  float: left;
  left: -50%;
}

.element3 {
  width: 33.3%;
  float: right;
}
```